How can I properly set up custom rewrite rules in WordPress to handle URLs like https://example.com/single-staff/12/abc
I'm working with WordPress and have created a page called "single-staff." The URL https://example.com/single-staff works fine, but accessing https://example.com/single-staff/12/abc results in a 404 error.
I added some code to the function.php file and rebuilt the permalinks, but the issue persists.
add_filter('query_vars', 'gp_gotcha_queryvars' );
function gp_gotcha_queryvars( $qvars ){
        $qvars[] = 'id';
        $qvars[] = 'name';

        return $qvars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'gp_rewrite_url');
function gp_rewrite_url(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'single-staff/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=single-staff&id=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    //flush_rewrite_rules();
}

What's the issue?
I want to be able to access URLs in the format https://example.com/single-staff/12/abc and capture the parameters 12 and abc.

What about single-staff/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/??

Also, I would discourage using any of the default query vars such as name, it is possible WordPress might be doing something because these are being set. I'd even go so far as to recommend prefixing your variables so that they are more obvious that they are special for anyone debugging in the future.
